# Practical High Current Transistor Connections

Tags: power-supply, power, mosfet

I'm designing a power supply with n+1 redundancy implemented with MOSFETs and an OR-ing FET controller.  The power supplies are each rated for 35.7A output at 28V (TDK-Lambda CPFE1000FI28) and parallel operation behind diodes for redundancy is explicitly supported - so far so good.  Does anyone have any practical tips for making the high current connection to the MOSFET?  I'll add that the MOSFET hasn't been chosen yet.  A monster like an IXFN360N10T in a SOT-227 package is obviously the easiest but the gate capacitance is about an order of magnitude more than the FET controller recommends.  Right now, I'm looking at something like a SUM50020EL on a 3 oz board with ~550 mil traces but was wondering if there's another solution I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 2):

Current sharing on redundant DCDC converters requires accurate voltage matching and accurate current detection with share splitting communication between the supplies.  Diode Or SHARING often requires a preload of 5% to 10% to achieve stability with no loads from my experience as resonance can occur from each driver sharing the same current sense see each other’s current pump as a disturbance.

Another way to achieve redundancy is by multi-phase drivers that operate in parallel , not by splitting the load but by enabling parallel drivers on load demand.

Such an example is https://www.powersystemsdesign.com/articles/multiphase-dcdc-converters/39/4250

Comment: I tried to read the linked example but found a ridiculously long paragraph. I skimmed the very long thing and found a term I don't know nothing about it: ***Stage Shedding***. So as, usual, I googled: "EXPLAINER | Stage 6 to 8 load-shedding and what it could mean for you - 2019dec0, 20,639 views":
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JFskawuykTw. I watched the video and found it good. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, these converters have a load sharing provision and we have used it on other systems that don’t require n+1 redundancy.  However, the manual for this specific converter has this interesting blurb in the section about paralleling with OR-ing diodes: “where it is imperative that a single unit fault does not cause any downtime, it is advised that the parallel sense (PS) and Vshare (VSH) be left disconnected between units”.  The manual also states that connecting PS and VSH between units drops their power limit to 85% of nameplate capacity which is something I’d like to avoid if possible.

Comment: It seems there are tradeoffs with heat rise, or stability so derating with fault tolerance for N+1 operation reduces max power with 4~6 units.  Sharing causes instability on startup and possible instability under light loads or full load.  (Too many cooks in the kitchen)